# Is there a deeplink to launch Facebook live video on Facebook iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, deeplink, live-video

I want to redirect my customers from my website to Facebook iOS app to make them watch a specific Facebook page's live video, but I couldn't find the link scheme.

This is sample browser link if you need:
https://www.facebook.com/Selcuklu.Tesbih1742/videos/678498876284596/

The stream is not going to be live, this is an old, deleted live stream. I am able to get the live video link from Graph API when the stream is live, dont worry about that.

I tried to use https://app.urlgeni.us/ to get a link, android works but not iOS.

Comment: Is your application a web app or native app?

Comment: @VictorJohn it is a website, web app i guess

Comment: Got it. For redirecting to Facebook iOS app through a website, you should see this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/sharing-to-stories/ios-developers/  it's an official docs that will tell you exactly how to do that.  For example, if you want to open/share a story to Facebook Story then the deeplink should write `facebook-stories://share`  custom scheme. If you want to open a facebook friend profile page then you should write `fb://profile/<id>` custom scheme .

Comment: I don't think this is what I need sir